# Trouble getting DatePickerAndroid to work on button press React Native

Tags: react-native

Trying to use react native and am having trouble binding the function for the date picker to a button press. There are no errors being thrown but the datepicker doesn't show up when I press the button, why would this be?

```js
const dp =  {
  async datePicker(){
      try {
        const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
          date: new Date()
        });
      } catch ({code, message}) {
        console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
      }
    }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Button title="hello"  onPress={() => dp.datePicker()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
})
```

I am also confused as to why the function needs to be defined in a constant and how I would go about accessing the date after a user has selected it

Answer (score 0):

TRy this :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
 datePicker = async() =>{
      try {
        const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
          date: new Date()
        });
      } catch ({code, message}) {
        console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
      }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Button title="hello"  onPress={() => this.datePicker()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
})
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts